# How can I remove the hover effect of progress bar on youtube embedded player?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I have embedded a youtube video in my HTML page. Since the video screen size is too small, the hover effect on the progress bar is getting cropped.
How can I stop this hover effect on the progress bar?
[image: Hover effect]

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to disable the thumbnail preview in YouTube's native embed players. But you can disable the player controls altogether by appending `?controls=0` to the embed URL.

Here is an example, `<iframe width='340' height='200' src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/MpGLUVbqoYQ?controls=0"></iframe>`

Answer (score 0):

the previous comment has it right. if youre using the API with javascript it might be best to use it like this:

```
        function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
            player = new YT.Player('player', {
                height: '390',
                width: '640',
                videoId: 'videoId',
                playerVars: {
                    'controls': 0
                }
            });
        }
```